# angularjs offline docs is not loading contents in the browser

Tags: angularjs

I have just downloaded angular-1.2.23 zip archive files. After full extract, when I tries to open file angular-1.2.23/docs/index.html. It does not loads content, it just shows "loading..." Please look at the screenshots, I have opened the firebug console as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I need to run python -m SimpleHTTPServer on my ubuntu to properly see the documentation.